# Exception handling inside Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception, task

```
using System;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
namespace TestApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() => Activity.Run());
        }
    }

    public static class Activity
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            const string sql = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = 103368 FOR UPDATE";

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var connection = new OracleConnection())
                    {
                        connection.ConnectionString = "xxx";
                        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                        {
                            command.CommandText = sql;
                            connection.Open();

                            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                            if (reader.Read())
                            {
                                var x = reader[0];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //ERROR LOGGING HERE
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when the `command.ExecuteReader()` has to wait a long time(several minutes) because the row in the database has been locked by some other process, the entire thread just dies. If it has to wait less, for example one minute it works. In the case it dies the code never reaches the catch block.

I do not want to move the exception handling out of the task. It should be separate process to work continuously. In the case of an exceptions it should log the exception details and go on to process next row from the database. If any other exceptions occur the catch block works fine.

1. Could this be a database command timeout issue?
2. What ever the issue is why doesn't it reach the catch block?

Comment: why did you use `while(true)`? it is an infinite loop

Comment: This task is meant to run continuously. This example is simplified, in real code I have cancellationToken too of course to stop the process.

Comment: do you know exact line where your app fails? is it `connection.Open()`?

Comment: While debugging the code stops at command.ExecuteReader(). This is ok because the row is locked and I have not said NOWAIT in my query. But the execution does not continue if it has to wait several minutes.

Comment: could be [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614035/timeout-for-oracledatareader-read-method) for you

Comment: Well, this solution is about setting timeout. For me it is OK the timeout to be infinite(=0). My goal is that my background task would be able to continue even if it has been waiting for DB 5 minutes for example. At the moment it just dies silently for some reason. When it has to wait for example 1 minute, it is able to continue it's work.