# Ado.net OracleCommand does not throw timeout exception (executing stored procedure)

Tags: c#, ado.net, oraclecommand

I am executing a ORACLE Stored procedure using `System.OracleClient.OracleCommand` and set `CommandTimeout = 5; (for example)`

But I want to set a timeout such that if the command object execution takes more than say 5 minutes it should get aborted (getting exception...`OracleException`) so that I can show an error message to the user. Let me know how can this be done. This is my written code example.

```
    try
    {
        _dbConnectionString.Open();               
        var cmdOracle = new OracleCommand("hfghgh", _dbConnectionString)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        };
        OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmdOracle);               
        cmdOracle.Parameters["inputParam"].Value = 1;                
        tran =_dbConnectionString.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
        cmdOracle.Transaction = tran;
        cmdOracle.CommandTimeout = 5;

        await cmdOracle.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        tran.Commit();
        return res = cmdOracle.Parameters["outputParam"].Value.ToString();
    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        dynamic exOra = ex;
        int errorNo = exOra.Number;
        if (errorNo == 01013)
        {
            throw new ResponseFailException(ex);
        }
        else
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeout for OracleDataReader.Read Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614035/timeout-for-oracledatareader-read-method)

Comment: I need to set timer and count seconds in the backend part using your suggested way. Is there any way to set CommandTimeout any value (for example 5) and get exception? (timeout)

Comment: Based on the duplicate - no, it doesn't look like it.

Comment: My problem is related with throw exception for timeout. I have assigned (for example) 5 seconds to (CommandTimeout = 5) but it does not help to get exception. How can I do it ?