# How to avoid connection lost issue with database when reading millions of data with datareader?

Tags: c#, ado.net, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a class library which reads data from database table.Now this database table is client database and my application only have connection string and sql query to open connection,execute sql query,read data and perform some operation. 
What this operation is, its bit complicated(basically business rules).

Now the user submits the sql query in specific format that my class library knows what columns to pick from that sql query results.

I dont know number of records that my class library would be dealing with. It could be **100,200 or millions of data** too.

Currently class library is dealing with `90 millions of data which resides on oracle`. I am reading this data using `SQLDATAREADER`.

Now the problem is to avoid memory exception i am reading data using sql data reader but reading 90 millions of data 1 by 1 and then performing some operations on those each records,connection will remain open for that time and currently i am facing the issue of connection lost :

```
ORA-03135: connection lost contact
```

1 Solution may be to read data in chunk but as i said i dont know number of records i could be dealing with and also SQL query is not in my hands as it is submitted by user which is picked up by my class library.

Is there anything I can do to avoid connection issue?

**Update :**

```
public class LongRunningTask : IDisposable
{
        public void Start(DbConnection connection, string sql)
        {
            using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                connection.Open();
                using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    //read 1 by 1 record and pass it to algorithm to do some complex processing
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Algorithm is not slow and that is not a problem.Main problem is reading part which is **slow in case of current 90 millions of data from ORACLE**.

I have tested with 100 millions of data against SQL SERVER where I have not face this issue(sometime transport layer error though) although this process is taking quite alot of time.I am facing this issue only with ORACLE.

Comment: the query that you're executing - is it text, or a cursor, or...? there's some context [on this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614035/timeout-for-oracledatareader-read-method) which suggests it behaves differently for different scenarios - very vexing; however, I find it odd that it would fail in this way if you're still receiving data.

Comment: @MarcGravell Currently its a simple sql query "select col1,col2,col3,col4 from table" which have primary key on col1

Comment: and just to be clear: does the error happen *before* you start receiving data, or *while* you are receiving data?

Comment: @MarcGravell As of now I dont know where exactly this is happening but i assume when i am consuming data through data reader and as mentioned in the question, for each we apply some business rules.I have seen that this process was running for quite >4 hours and then suddenly got an error : Connection Lost

Comment: Is it possible to show some of the code for how you’re processing the data? When there are memory concerns and possibly large numbers of records to be processed, I would look to try and put my method that is returning data into an iterator block (using “yield return”) I would then use something like MoreLinq.Batch to process the data in reasonable sized chunks. This gives you the best of both worlds IMHO

Comment: @TimRobinson Hi.I have updated my question with some code and more explanation.

Comment: @MarcGravell I have updated my question with some code and more explanation

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow I hate to say it, but from the description, it *sounds* like a glitch in the oracle ADO.NET provider when dealing with very high volumes; that's not easy to work around if you can't change the query

Comment: @MarcGravell But current sql query is pretty simple.still in case if i can change the query than what should be the change in order to solve this problem?

Comment: If you read the result with the DataReader without storing it on client side (readonly), do you still get the Connection Timeout? If no, what is the execution time then?

Comment: @FrankNielsen I am frequently getting timeout issue with 90 millions of data and with 90 millions i have kept processing at 1:00 PM and i got connection timeout at 5:30 PM

Comment: My point is that maybe you can optimize the client storage, so you can process (read) the data faster.

Comment: @FrankNielsen Sorry i did not understand by client storage.Could you please elaborate a little.Thanks

Comment: How does the client/end user handle all these millions of data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189823/discussion-between-ilovestackoverflow-and-frank-nielsen).

Comment: About client storage, when you have read a row from the DataReader do you store it to a file on disk? Try skipping that part and only read data, just to investigate how fast that is.

Comment: I can't imagine what kind of data processing needs to get/fetch 100 millions of records... In a short, you have to work on much less portion of data. I agree with @FrankNielsen that end user is not able to handle such huge portion of data.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a good idea to have a data reader open for many hours. Even if everything is configured correctly, there may be transient error somewhere on the wire (like the transport layer errors you mentioned).

You can add retry logic in your client code to make it more robust. One way of doing this is to track the last processed record and try to reconnect and "resume" from that position on connection failure.

```
private const int MAX_RETRY = 10;
private const int RETRY_INTERVAL_MS = 1000;
private string lastProcessedPosition = null;

public void Start(string connectionString, string sql)
{
    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
    for (var i = 0; i < MAX_RETRY; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Process(connString, sql, lastProcessedPosition)) return;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            exceptions.Add(ex);
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(RETRY_INTERVAL_MS);
    }
    throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
}
```

Your `Process()` method will reconnect and skip already-processed rows:

```
public bool Process(string connString, string sql, string resumeFromPosition = null)
{
    using ()// init your connection, command, reader
    {
        if (resumeFromPosition != null)
        {
            while (dr.Read() && dr.ToPositionString() != resumeFromPosition)
            {
                // skipping already processed records
            }
        }
        while (dr.Read)
        {
            // Do your complex processing

            // You can do this every N records if accuracy is not critical
            lastProcessedPosition = dr.ToPositionString();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

`dr.ToPositionString()` is an extension method that you create to make a row unique based on your table schema.

Comment: Dont you think  while (dr.Read() && dr.ToPositionString() != resumeFromPosition) will do the same because here data reader will again gonna read all the records but its just that we are just skipping algorithm part

Comment: If you are dealing with large data and reading the data from data reader takes the majority of the time, then you have to move the skipping logic to the server side. Append to the `sql` in a way a filter is added: such as primary id, row number, the order-by column, or even a custom function for each table.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is what I have used in the past to read large data sets from the database, but process them in chunks:

First, I choose to implement a method for getting a Database Connection. Note that I set the ConnectionTimeout to 0 because I know this process is going to be long running.

```
private static OracleConnection GetConnection()
{
    return new OracleConnection(new OracleConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        //TODO: Set other connection string properties
        ConnectionTimeout = 0
    }.ConnectionString);
}
```

Next, I want to have some generic "GetData" method that reads the data from the database. Note that it's return type is explicitly "IEnumerable". You can strongly type it instead of having it be generic, but it needs to stay returning an IEnumerable in order to take advantage of "yield return".

Also note that I've set the CommandTimeout = 0 because I know this process will be long running.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(string sql)
{
    using (var conn = GetConnection())
    {
        if (ConnectionState.Closed == conn.State) conn.Open();

        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql; //TODO: Make sure you do standard sql injection prevention

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //We want to optimize the number of round trips to the DB our reader makes.
                //Setting the FetchSize this way will make the reader bring back 5000 records
                //with every trip to the DB
                reader.FetchSize = reader.RowSize * 5000;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                    reader.GetValues(values);
                    //This assumes that type T has a constructor that takes in an object[]
                    //and the mappings of object[] to properties is done in that constructor
                    yield return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { values });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next I want to have some method that implements the fancy business logic/algorithm:

```
public static void ProcessBusinessLogic<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    //TODO Implement fancy business logic here
}
```

Lastly, I need a method that will wrap these 2 methods and use them together. I also need a way to make sure that I'm processing the records in "chunks" so that I don't try and load millions of records into memory and crash the system.

In order to process the data in chunks, I utilize a class from the MoreLinq nuget library for MoreEnumerable.Batch. This will allow me to "chunk" the results from my GetData method into more appropriately sized "batches". Utilizing this, I will be able to make sure that I never load into memory more records than whatever I set as the batch size.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var batch in GetData<string>("hello world").Batch(50000))
    {
        ProcessBusinessLogic(batch);
    }
}
```

So, to put the entire thing together, this test app has 2 classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using MoreLinq;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace ReadLargeDataset
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var batch in GetData<string>("hello world").Batch(50000))
            {
                ProcessBusinessLogic(batch);
            }
        }

        public static void ProcessBusinessLogic<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            //TODO Implement fancy business logic here
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(string sql)
        {
            using (var conn = GetConnection())
            {
                if (ConnectionState.Closed == conn.State) conn.Open();

                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = sql; //TODO: Make sure you do standard sql injection prevention

                    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        //We want to optimize the number of round trips to the DB our reader makes.
                        //Setting the FetchSize this way will make the reader bring back 5000 records
                        //with every trip to the DB
                        reader.FetchSize = reader.RowSize * 5000;

                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
                            reader.GetValues(values);
                            //This assumes that type T has a constructor that takes in an object[]
                            //and the mappings of object[] to properties is done in that constructor
                            yield return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { values });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static OracleConnection GetConnection()
        {
            return new OracleConnection(new OracleConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                //TODO: Set other connection string properties
                ConnectionTimeout = 0
            }.ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
#region License and Terms
// MoreLINQ - Extensions to LINQ to Objects
// Copyright (c) 2009 Atif Aziz. All rights reserved.
// 
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
// 
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
// 
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.
#endregion

// ReSharper disable CheckNamespace
namespace MoreLinq
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;

    public static class MoreEnumerable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Batches the source sequence into sized buckets.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TSource">Type of elements in <paramref name="source"/> sequence.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source sequence.</param>
        /// <param name="size">Size of buckets.</param>
        /// <returns>A sequence of equally sized buckets containing elements of the source collection.</returns>
        /// <remarks> This operator uses deferred execution and streams its results (buckets and bucket content).</remarks>

        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Batch<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size)
        {
            return Batch(source, size, x => x);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Batches the source sequence into sized buckets and applies a projection to each bucket.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="TSource">Type of elements in <paramref name="source"/> sequence.</typeparam>
        /// <typeparam name="TResult">Type of result returned by <paramref name="resultSelector"/>.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">The source sequence.</param>
        /// <param name="size">Size of buckets.</param>
        /// <param name="resultSelector">The projection to apply to each bucket.</param>
        /// <returns>A sequence of projections on equally sized buckets containing elements of the source collection.</returns>
        /// <remarks> This operator uses deferred execution and streams its results (buckets and bucket content).</remarks>

        public static IEnumerable<TResult> Batch<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size,
            Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            if (size <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(size));
            if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(resultSelector));
            return BatchImpl(source, size, resultSelector);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<TResult> BatchImpl<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size,
            Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector)
        {
            Debug.Assert(source != null);
            Debug.Assert(size > 0);
            Debug.Assert(resultSelector != null);

            TSource[] bucket = null;
            var count = 0;

            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                if (bucket == null)
                {
                    bucket = new TSource[size];
                }

                bucket[count++] = item;

                // The bucket is fully buffered before it's yielded
                if (count != size)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Select is necessary so bucket contents are streamed too
                yield return resultSelector(bucket.Select(x => x));

                bucket = null;
                count = 0;
            }

            // Return the last bucket with all remaining elements
            if (bucket != null && count > 0)
            {
                yield return resultSelector(bucket.Take(count));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me and for your valuable time.Really really appreciated.Problem here would be since i dont know the number of records i would be dealing with(100,10000,10000000000 etc...),how to choose appropriate batch size in case if records are 50 or 100?

Comment: The batch size that you choose is always just the “maximum” batch size. If you set it to batch size of 500, but there’s only 200 records, then you’ll just end up processing 1 batch of 200 records. If by chance there were 501 records, then you would process 1 batch of 500 records and 1 batch of 1 record.

Comment: I should add that if you are providing a library for someone else to use, you might want to expose a way for the end user to pass in the desired batch count, but also set a default batch size of something reasonable....say 1000 records or so

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

I have run into this before and it was because of a firewall rule on my corporate network.

Long answer and unsolicited advice:

I think the main problem you have is with your application design. If you’re going to be processing millions of records it could take a long time… A very long time depending on what you have to do.
I worked on an application to encrypt 100 million card numbers at rest in a database and it took 3 weeks to finish. Dealing with really big data is tricky; I ran into all kinds of issues. 
Here would be some of my recommendations.

1)  You’re going to hear that your problem is with your timeout settings. This might not be it. Where I worked we had firewall rules that would kill database connections after a period of time (15 or 30 min I don’t remember) and it took us weeks to figure out why our connections would just drop.

2)  Pulling back millions of records at a time is not a great idea.

3)  You should put some SQL injection prevention in your code.

4)  I would recommend using an ORM like Entity Framework this makes looping though and chunking easier.

Comment: But when processing 90 millions of data with SQL SERVER then i am not facing connection timeout issues(except sometime facing transport layer problem).This issue only comes for oracle so lets say we do have a firewall rules than why it doesnt kill sql server connection and why oracle connection only?

Comment: Are the SQL Server and the Oracle Db running on the same port? Different ports have different firewall rules.
Try creating a console app that keeps a connection open to the Oracle Db. See if it dies after a set period of time.

Comment: Doubt its a port rule...could be a query governor configured in Oracle itself. SQL Server has 'em too, but it may just not be set in SQL Server the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot you fetch all the data and keep all of them into some in-memory object and then release the connection to DB; post that process your complicated subiness rules, once done and you need to update this data back to the DB open the connection again and do a bulk update.

Hope I am making some sense.

Comment: Fetching all the data and keeping in memory will crash the memory hence using data reader to avoid that

Comment: If it is mandatory to deal with such huge data then you need to have a good supporting hardware or else you need to change the logic of fetching data which in your case is not an option.

Comment: I mean its not fixed that every time my class library would be dealing with millions of  records although since its a legacy database(ie client database) so its really hard to say that with how much data my class library would be dealing with but i just want to make sure that there is no problem in dealing with millions of data too :)

Answer (score 1):

I will never advocate to bring that much of data in the memory regardless of connection state. At one side, I am not sure how big an entity is? which data types are used while making the columns.

Please make sure followings :

1. You really need the whole entity to perform complicated logic to execute ( i.e. to run business rule )? Besides this, how many columns do exist in a single entire entity?
2. Is it possible just to fetch only the required data? ( e.g. only required columns on the basis of which you will map or perform business rules ? Try to avoid loading entire database row unless you are sure that each and every column is participating.)
3. Is there any way to associate this complicated logic to database records directly? If so, transfer these rules into database and use stored procedures to perform and calculate these rules there instead on memory.

If I would be at your place, I would do mix of the things. Some part of the problem will remain in database and where I consider it necessary to do things in memory, I will perform things there.

Post some specific and concrete logic and data entity , so that we can analyze the problem more.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a situation where *either* there's a sketchy connection to Oracle or there's policy that kills your process after some kind of timeout (not on your side - on the server). SQL Server and Oracle both have the concept of a query governor, and they could be configured in different ways.

There are strategies to overcome these barriers...and they all revolve around batching your query. The problem is how to make sure you pick back up where you left off.

Both Oracle and SQL Server have the idea of `offset` and `fetch first n` in queries. This is specifically designed to make *paged* queries, which could help in your case.

The basic setup is:

```
select 
  columns... 
from 
  data sources...
where 
  some conditions...
offset @offset
fetch first @pageSize rows
```

..and then you can arrange your process to run the select repeatedly, passing new values for @offset and @pageSize as you go.

If your query varies but is a regular select-type of statement, you could append the `offset` and `fetch` clauses to the query in your processing code.

You have to make your process a little more robust in the face of *actual* connectivity problems, but that's pretty straightforward.

You also want to keep your connect time as short as possible. The reason you want to do this is that most databases support connection pooling, so that it's cheap and easy to create connections if you let the poller recycle them. Also, the reason DBAs put governors on their queries is because developers are forever doing things like `cmd.CommandTimeout = 0;`

```
public class LongRunningTask
{
  const long pageSize = 100000L; //--> ...or whatever the market will bear
  const int retryLimit = 3;
  public void Start( ConnectionFactory factory, string sql )
  {
    var done = false;
    var page = 0L;
    var index = 0L;
    var retries = 0;
    var retrying = false;
    while ( !done )
    {
      try
      {
        using ( var connection = factory.CreateConnection( ) )
        {
          using ( var cmd = connection.CreateCommand( ) )
          {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.Parameters.Add( factory.CreateParameter( "@pageSize", SqlDbType.BigInt ) );
            cmd.Parameters.Add( factory.CreateParameter( "@offset", SqlDbType.BigInt ) );
            cmd.Parameters[ "@pageSize" ].Value = pageSize - ( retrying ? index : 0 );
            cmd.Parameters[ "@offset" ].Value = page + ( retrying ? index : 0 );
            connection.Open( );
            using ( var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader( ) )
            {
              index = retrying ? index : 0;
              retrying = false;
              done = !dr.HasRows; //--> didn't get anything, we're done!
              while ( dr.Read( ) )
              {
                //read 1 by 1 record and pass it to algorithm to do some complex processing
                index++;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        page++;
      }
      catch ( Exception ex )
      {
        Console.WriteLine( ex );
        if ( retryLimit < retries++ ) throw;
        retrying = true;
      }
    }
  }
}

public  class ConnectionFactory
{
  public DbConnection CreateConnection( )
  {
    return //... a DbConnection
  }
  public DbParameter CreateParameter( string parameterName, SqlDbType type, int length = 0 )
  {
    return //... a DbParameter
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going through this post in an attempt to find an answer to another problem. You have an interesting problem here.

If you are not displaying the data that is being retrieved and are interested in some final result, then the best way to do that would be to write Oracle Server Side PL/SQL and implement your logic in PL/SQL Packages.

I have earlier written server-side code in PL/SQL that comprises complex business logic and generates summary information at different levels. The client program would then read that generated set only.

Answer (score 0):

You can set connection timeout limit like this:

```
command.CommandTimeout = 60; //The time in seconds to wait for the command to execute. The default is 30 seconds.
```

Comment: I already have CommandTimeout set to infinity(0) but still this issue persist

Comment: I have run into issues before and found that there are multiple timeouts that are possible to be set. You should be able to set the “ConnectionTimeout” on the actual OracleConnection object as well as the “CommandTimeout” on the specific OracleCommand object. It’s easy to miss one or the other of these timeouts.